# Customizing Woocoomerce Cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I want to add checkbox on my Cart page of woocommerce when user check the box it will automatically subscribe them for my product. I have bought woocommerce subcriber plugin but I don't know how to add checkbox which will have this functionality in cart page.

Comment: If you purchased WooCommerce Subscriptions, take a look at their [Subscribe All The Things](https://github.com/Prospress/woocommerce-subscribe-all-the-things) plugin

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer to the best of my knowledge given that I am not proficient with woocommerce. But the general idea is that, you add your checkbox on the cart page of the theme and pass the the value via form data(like name="subscribe" value="True/false") to the data handler(most probably the next page in the checkout cycle which would be delivery or payment options page), which will then call the plugin and pass the subscriber info to it. I would say that it would make sense to put the checkbox where you collect customer info but hey your site, your choice.

Sorry if this is a very generic answer and not a detailed one. I am very new to this myself. Best of luck.